# Is it possible to use onchange with 2 fields? -Odoo 8

Tags: python, onchange, odoo-8

I currently have an onchange function that works every time I change the user but I wondering if it is possible that this function can work on 2 fields using an OR? for example: add text to description field if user OR status is changed in the ticket.

```
@api.onchange('responsible_id' or 'state')
def _update_resolution(self):
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z" #datetime format
    user = self.env.user

    context_tz = pytz.utc
    if (user.partner_id.tz):
        context_tz = pytz.timezone(user.partner_id.tz)

    now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    now_user_dt = now_utc.astimezone(context_tz)

    resolution = ""
    resolution_format = "** {0:s}: {1:s}:-\n{2:s}"
    if (self.resolution):
        resolution = self.resolution
        resolution_format = "** {0:s}: {1:s}:-\n\n\n{2:s}"

    self.resolution = resolution_format.format(user.name, str(now_user_dt.strftime(fmt)), resolution)
```

Not getting any error but it is not working as I expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following,

```
@api.onchange('responsible_id','state')
def _update_resolution(self):
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z" #datetime format
    user = self.env.user

    context_tz = pytz.utc
    if (user.partner_id.tz):
        context_tz = pytz.timezone(user.partner_id.tz)

    now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    now_user_dt = now_utc.astimezone(context_tz)

    resolution = ""
    resolution_format = "** {0:s}: {1:s}:-\n{2:s}"
    if (self.resolution):
        resolution = self.resolution
        resolution_format = "** {0:s}: {1:s}:-\n\n\n{2:s}"

    self.resolution = resolution_format.format(user.name, str(now_user_dt.strftime(fmt)), resolution)
```